# Create a tile with `div` that would fill all the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a tile with random colors in a list that would fill the entire page.
There's a couple of questions that I want to ask here. The `random_color` variable only applies to the first box and not the second box. Also, how would I dynamically and automatically create divs that would have random background colors, just like the first box?

```js
var version_1 = ['#111111', '#222222', '#333333', '#444444'];
var random_color = version_1[Math.floor(Math.random() * version_1.length)];
document.getElementById('box').style.background = random_color;
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#box {
  width: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  background: #00F;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}
#innerContent {
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   right: 10px;
   top: 10px;
   bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
   <div id="innerContent">
       Box 1
   </div>
</div>
<div id="box">
   <div id="innerContent">
       Box 2
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First thing `ID` Must Be Unique. Use `class` if you want to apply for multiple places

Comment: Are you trying to just set a background or do you specifically need each color in a separate element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the `id` to a `class`. Secondly, you want to change you logic for determining color as right now, every box will be the same color since `random_color` is only being determined once. Try this

```
const version_1 = ['#111111', '#222222', '#333333', '#444444'];
const boxEls = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for (let el of boxEls) {
  let random_color = version_1[Math.floor(Math.random() * version_1.length)];
  el.style.backgroundColor = random_color;
}
```

With this code above, you are running the Math.random() for each box.

Answer (score 2):

Id is not for multiple elements. It should be unique in the document. I recommend you a 'class' for this.

```html
<div class="box">
   <div class="innerContent">
       Box 1
   </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <div class="innerContent">
       Box 2
   </div>
</div>
```

Also if you want to dynamically create div elements, use `document.createElement("div")`. This will return HTMLElement object and you can manipulate it with javascript.

```js
const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.className = "box";
newDiv.innerText = "New Box!";
newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#ff8888";
```

Finally, for a random background colors, you should use `Math.random()` properly. Because, `Math.random()` returns random value between 0 and 1, so if you want to use them as color, you should multiply 255 to them.

```js
const r = Math.random() * 255;
const g = Math.random() * 255;
const b = Math.random() * 255;

div.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` to select all the divs with box id and then change the backgroundColor of every box using forEach loop.

```js
var version_1 = ['#111111', '#222222', '#333333', '#444444'];
var random_color = version_1[Math.floor(Math.random() * version_1.length)];
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('#box');
boxes.forEach((box) => box.style.backgroundColor = random_color);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#box {
  width: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  background: #00F;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}
#innerContent {
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   right: 10px;
   top: 10px;
   bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
   <div id="innerContent">
       Box 1
   </div>
</div>
<div id="box">
   <div id="innerContent">
       Box 2
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would only set all of the boxes to the same color since you would be computing the random color value only once and applying it to all boxes.

Comment: This answer has several problems: it does not describe how to create the multiple divs that are required by the question, it assumes repeated use of the same id attribute which is not legal HTML and it puts the same color in each tile as @Kyruski has pointed out.